# Черепашка не хочет двигаться

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle

```
import turtle

win = turtle.Screen()
win.bgcolor("Black")
win.setup(1000, 1000)

grid = turtle.Turtle()
grid.hideturtle()
grid.speed(0)
grid.color("Green")
grid.penup()
grid.goto(900,-1000)
grid.pendown()
grid.goto(900,1000)
```

Я просто не понимаю почему черепашка не хочет рисовать сетку дальше!
Она доходит до места откуда начинает рисовать и всё. Я опускаю ручку, а дальше она не идёт

Comment: А это должно быть `grid.speed(0)`?

Comment: Это максимальная скорость, чтобы моментально рисовалось

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас черепашка вышла за экран, поэтому не видно ее линии.

И еще, начальная точка рисования черепашки -- центр (0, 0), размер экрана у вас 1000x1000, поэтому сделав перемещение до точки 900x-1000 это почти в 2 раза расстояния до края из начальной точки. Например, перемещение в 500x0 это справа к краю (`grid.goto(500, 0)`) и получится горизонтальная линия

Для наглядности:

- Оставлю рисование линии от начальной точки
- Сделаю разный цвет линий
- Уменьшу масштаб рисования линий

Пример:

```
import turtle

win = turtle.Screen()
win.bgcolor("Black")
win.setup(1000, 1000)

n = 5

grid = turtle.Turtle()
grid.hideturtle()
grid.speed(0)
grid.color("Green")
# grid.penup()
grid.goto(900/n,-1000/n)  # Конечная точка: x=900, y=-1000

grid.color("red")
grid.pendown()
# т.к. точка x не менялась, то линия нарисуется вертикально
grid.goto(900/n,1000/n)  # Конечная точка: x=900, y=1000

turtle.done()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]